# Proving Inequality using Induction $a^n-b^n \leq na^{n-1}(a-b)$

Tags: inequality, induction

I was trying to prove this inequality using induction, but couldn't do.

Question: Suppose $a$ and $b$ are real numbers with $0 < b < a$. Prove that if $n$ is a positive integer, then:

$$a^n-b^n \leq na^{n-1}(a-b)$$

Comment: What happens when "n" is not a positive integer? Looks like the answer that uses the MVT holds but does the marked answer hold as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will want to use that $$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-k-1}b^{k}$$

What can you say about the powers of $a,b$ given $0<b<a$?*

**SPOILER**

> Since $0<b<a$, we have $0<b^k<a^k$

thus

> $$\begin{align} a^n-b^n&=(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-k-1}b^{k}\\&<(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-k-1}a^{k}\\&=(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1}\\&=(a-b)na^{n-1}\end{align}$$

Comment: It's actually 0<b<a....

Comment: A very nice argument +1.

Comment: @greendragons I edited.

Comment: interesting and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

You may use the mean value theorem to show this:
Define $f(x) = x^n$ on $[b, a]$, clearly, $f(x)$ is differentiable in $(b, a)$ and continuous on $[b, a]$. By MVT, there exists $\xi \in (b, a)$ such that
$$a^n - b^n = f(a) - f(b) = f'(\xi)(a - b) = n\xi^{n - 1}(a - b) \leq na^{n - 1}(a - b)$$
as $\xi < a$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another somewhat related inequality: 
$$ a^n - b^n > n(a-b)(ab)^{(n-1)/2} $$ where $ a > b > 0 $ and $ n \geq 1 $. Here is a simple proof: 
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-k-1}b^{k}$$ Now apply AM-GM inequality on summation terms:

\begin{align} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-k-1}b^{k} &< n \sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{a^{n-k-1}b^{k}}} \\
                               &= n \sqrt[n]{a^{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{(n-k-1)}}  \, b^{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{k}}} \\
                               &= n \sqrt[n]{a^{n(n-1)/2} \, b^{n(n-1)/2}} \\
                               &= n (ab)^{(n-1)/2} 
\end{align}

Answer (score -2):

The proof proceeds by induction.

(1) First base case $(n = 1)$: here $$a^1 −b^1 \le 1 \times a^0(a−b) = a − b$$,
so the statement holds.

(2) Inductive Hypothesis: Now suppose that $a^k − b^k < ka^{k−1}(a − b)$, where $0<  b < a$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

(3) Inductive Step:
We want to show that

$$a^{k+1} − b^{k+1} < (k+1)a^{k}(a − b)$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
a^{k+1} − b^{k+1} &= a^{k+1}- a^k \times b + a^k \times b − b^{k+1} \\
&= a^k(a − b) + b(a^k − b^k) \\
&\leq a^k(a − b) + b \times ka^{k−1}(a− b) \quad\text{(By Inductive Hypothesis)}\\
&< a^k(a − b) + a \times ka^{k−1}(a − b) \quad\text{(Since a > b)}\\
&= a^k(a − b) + ka^{k}(a − b) \\
&= (k+1)a^k(a − b)
\end{align*}$$

Hence by induction $a^n-b^n \leq na^{n-1}(a-b)$ is true $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Please take a look at the following page: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference It explains how to use MathJax and how to format your posts, so that they become more readable.